# expo Facebook login access to birthday email

Tags: react-native, expo

how can I access to the email and birthday in expo facebook login ?

I only get the name and ID...

```
  async function logIn() {
    try {
      await Facebook.initializeAsync({
        appId: 'ID',
      });
      const { type, token, expirationDate, permissions, declinedPermissions } =
        await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({
          permissions: ['public_profile', 'email'],
        });
      if (type === 'success') {
        // Get the user's name using Facebook's Graph API
        const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`);
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data);
      } else {
        // type === 'cancel'
      }
    } catch ({ message }) {
      alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you see any data on the `declinedPermissions` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Code sample

```
 const response = await fetch(
      `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}&fields=id,name,email,about,picture`
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's about the Facebook Graph API. What you need is to write after your token and then move it to use this URL:

BASE FACEBOOK API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${response.authentication.accessToken}&fields=
```

EXAMPLE

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${response.authentication.accessToken}&fields=id,name,about,age_range,birthday,education,email,favorite_athletes,favorite_teams,first_name,gender,hometown,id_for_avatars,inspirational_people,install_type,installed,is_guest_user,languages,last_name,link,location,meeting_for,middle_name,name_format,political,quotes,relationship_status,shared_login_upgrade_required_by,short_name,significant_other,sports,supports_donate_button_in_live_video,token_for_business,video_upload_limits,website,accounts.limit(10){about,access_token,ad_campaign,affiliation,app_id,artists_we_like,attire,awards,band_interests,band_members,best_page,bio,birthday},albums{cover_photo,photos{picture,width,height,images},picture{height,url,width}},feed,friends{email,age_range,first_name,gender,hometown,languages,last_name,location,middle_name,likes},permissions{permission},picture.type(large)`
```

Some of them need permissions. This is the API's response:

EXAMPLE RESPOND

```
{ "id": "xxxxxx", "name": "Rayan Jaafar Mohammedameen", "age_range": { "min": 21 }, "birthday": "01/01/2001", "email": "rayandeveloperking2@gmail.com", "first_name": "Rayan", "gender": "male", "install_type": "UNKNOWN", "installed": true, "is_guest_user": false, "last_name": "Mohammedameen", "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/YXNpZADpBWEhWZAThRWl84QTJXZAV9VeWM1cFVIRU5xeFdJUlQzOWo5S0VCc3I1eUJiVDZAOWFJkenU5c2ZAyaFRvR0NTSUEzSVNDWGFWSHQ2N0VBVC1ndGpiS0tlelpNTnhWRmxtbjNOeTNwWG53cVd2R0tmWkFyV3cZD/", "middle_name": "Jaafar", "name_format": "{first} {last}", "short_name": "Rayan", "supports_donate_button_in_live_video": false, "token_for_business": "xxxxxxx", "video_upload_limits": { "length": 14460, "size": 28633115306 }, "albums": { "data": [ { "picture": { "data": { "url": "https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yC/r/gtEJuZGrBLG.jpg" } }, "id": "122078237557316" } ], "paging": { "cursors": { "before": "MTIyMDc4MjM3NTU3MzE2", "after": "MTIyMDc4MjM3NTU3MzE2" } } }, "friends": { "data": [ ], "summary": { "total_count": 0 } }, "permissions": { "data": [ { "permission": "user_birthday" }, { "permission": "user_hometown" }, { "permission": "user_location" }, { "permission": "user_likes" }, { "permission": "user_payment_tokens" }, { "permission": "user_photos" }, { "permission": "user_videos" }, { "permission": "user_friends" }, { "permission": "user_posts" }, { "permission": "user_gender" }, { "permission": "user_link" }, { "permission": "user_age_range" }, { "permission": "email" }, { "permission": "groups_show_list" }, { "permission": "public_profile" } ] } }`
```

For those that want permission, just ask and let the client accept and you are good.

For customizing the URL, you can change things at this link:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

And after that, just past the URL in the Gragh API after the fields:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${response.authentication.accessToken}&fields=
```

guide go to meta developer create app in dashbord app click tool on the top and click Graph API Explorer

hope it help

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the users e-mail address is to request extended permissions on the email field. The user must allow you to see this and you cannot get the e-mail addresses of the user's friends.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

You can do this if you are using Facebook connect by passing scope=email in the get string of your call to the Auth Dialog.

Comment: I passed the scope email look at the code above.   permissions: ['public_profile', 'email'],